# Passing collection to the xbre Rule

Tags: nxbre

I have a .NET object which is a collection, for example an `Employee` object containing list of employees.

I need to pass the same to the rules engine to do the looping inside the rule file.

Can you please help me with code to the same from .NET as well looping in `xbre` file. 
I have successfully passed an object with single record. However need to pass collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you pass the `EmployeeWrapper` object itself to NxBRE using the standard approach:

```
bre.RuleContext.SetObject("EmployeeWrapper", employeeWrapper);
```

then reflectively extract the list of employees with:

```
<ObjectLookup id="Employees" objectId="EmployeeWrapper" member="Employees" />
```

*assuming the `EmployeeWrapper` object has a property named `Employees` which returns the collection of employees*.

Then use a `ForEach` block to iterate the employees:

```
<ForEach id="Employee" valueId="Employees">
    ...
</ForEach>
```

Comment: @David. Is it possible to get this collection like array, for example someting like `<ObjectLookup id="Employees" objectId="EmployeeWrapper[0]" />` , foreach solution cant resolve my problem.

Comment: @vahidkargar The `NxBRE.Util.DataAccess#GetArrayColumnValue` static helper should allow you to get an array value. See example here: https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE/blob/master/NxBRE3/Rulefiles/test.xbre#L771-L774